# Solving a System of Equations with Cosine

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

How do I solve a system of equations when there is a cosine.

Here is the system:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a+b=77° \\ 
\cos(a)=\frac{y}{3.5} \\ 
\cos(a)=\frac{y+1}{3.5+x} \\
\cos(b)=\frac{y+1}{3.5} 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: We have $$a=\arccos \frac y{3.5}\text{  and } b=\arccos\frac{y+1}{3.5}$$ We can use $$\arccos x+\arccos y\left(xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}\right)$$